# Yeoman grunt-usemin generates empty html

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, grunt-usemin

I have a problem with grunt-usemin, that works correctly with the `build:js` tags, but when it reaches the `build:css` tag is erases everything in that file.

I have set up the web-app using the official Yeoman generator: `yo webapp`, then made some adaptations to work with my project. The folder tree is as follows:

```
/
- app
  |- bower_components
  |- content
  |- fonts
  |- images
  |- includes
  |- scripts
  |- styles
     index.php
     ...
- dist
...
```

So nothing fancy except for the `content` and `includes` that contain .php partials

There is a file `app/includes/html-scripts.php` that is correctly generated, containing these tags:

```
<!-- build:js(app) scripts/vendor/frameworks.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
...
<!-- build:js({app,.tmp}) scripts/main.js -->
<script src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

But the `app/includes/html-head.php` is emptied in the last step (`usemin`) of the `grunt build`. It contains:

```
<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/fonts.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<!-- endbuild -->
...
```

I've also tried with `build:css({.tmp,app})`, `build:css`, the same.

This is my `Gruntfile.js`: http://pastebin.com/9ZpjkGjY (I have tried with the `sass:dist` instead of `compass:dist`, same result)

Here is my `package.json`: http://pastebin.com/VAPwm71f

Can anyone help with an answer?

Comment: It appears that there is an issue in usemin's fileprocessor.js, not detecting linefeed correctly: var linefeed = /\r\n/g.test(result) ? '\r\n' : '\n'; This does not acount for files with mixed linefeeds, and it ignores the new OSX linefeed \r